# unicode characters suddenly appearing in asterisk CLI SSH console

Tags: command-line, ssh, unicode, asterisk

I have a mysterious issue. I connect to an Arch Linux virtual machine running asterisk. All of a sudden, anytime I enter the asterisk CLI, the SSH console spits out unicode character codes. What I am showing below is the result of moving the arrows. How can I get my normal display back?

```
aag ~ $ sudo asterisk -r
Connected to Asterisk 13.9.1 currently running on asterisk (pid = 1399)
asterisk*CLI> \U+4B01B\U+4B05B\U+4B041
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is discussed on the Asterisk forums here https://community.asterisk.org/t/cli-gibberish-prompt-and-input-appear-to-be-some-sort-of-unicode-characters/67382/15

It's caused when Asterisk uses external `libedit` (which is the default option in Asterisk if it's provided by the system, and Arch Linux provides it by default) with incompatible version.

One workaround is to compile Asterisk with `--with-libedit=internal`.
Other workaround is to downgrade `libedit` to a compatible version (e.g. libedit 20150325_3.1-2)

Comment: Just a hint for a non-invasive approach, get the proper versions of `libedit` (and `libtinfo` that it requires by itself) and use `LD_PRELOAD` instead of doing a system-wide library downgrade: `alias asterisk="LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libtinfo.so.5:/usr/local/lib/libedit.so.0.0.53 asterisk"`.  Of course this assumes you put these libraries in /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the PKGBUILD file and add `--with-libedit=internal` in the ./configure line.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure why it was downvoted - might the downvoter provide clarity? Also, what exactly does this PKGBUILD option do?

Comment: PKGBUILD is the file to build packages. Since asterisk is in AUR, you can download the PKGBUILD file, edit the file and then rebuild and reinstall the asterisk package. Alternatively you can downgrade the libedit package.

Answer (score 0):

Those are color/positions chars.

You have 2 options

1)Ensure you ssh client support same terminal type you have in TERM variable. To get it use

```
env|grep TERM
```

2) run asterisk console without color

> -n     Disable ANSI colors even on terminals capable of displaying
>   them.

So use

```
   asterisk -rn
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to help me. Regrettably, neither suggestions helped. Starting the asterisk CLI with the -rn switch did not change anything. 
I then removed the colors by editing ~/.bashrc and rebooting. Still getting the code gibberish though. 
I should add that locale indicates that asterisk (on arch linux) is using UTF-8, and the terminal software (putty) is also using xterm and UTF-8

Comment: Maybe your asterisk compiled in other environment without UTF-8. Try other encoding(in both terminal and putty).

Comment: I installed a completely fresh version of arch linux, and compiled asterisk anew from yaourt. Again, no joy. The linux environment works just fine, but as soon as I switch to asterisk things go awry. This only happens since a few weeks, which leads me to wonder whether it's a bug.

Comment: Arch linux is not so common. Sorry, can say nothing except i say above.